# Visual Studio 2015 SSDT-BI Designer Font Size

Tags: visual-studio, ssdt-bi

Something has changed in VS2015 in the past week which has caused all of my SSDT-BI design files to appear with a high level of zoom and increased font size. Everything else in VS is fine. I've tried everything in the font and other options that I appear to be related and nothing seems to make a difference. Notice how the text no longer fits in the boxes in the designer even after being scaled down to 70%. The font size in the "Connection Manager" window is significantly larger than the other VS windows.

[image]

I'd like to avoid reinstalling VS2015 if possible. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: I've encountered this as well using Visual Studio 2017. Would love to find an answer other than reinstalling SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way to fix this just through the config. Uninstalling SSDT-BI and reinstalling fixed the issue. A bit faster than reinstalling all of VS2015 but there should be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official fix for this; it seems that the issue has thus far been ignored by Microsoft.  However, I have noticed that it happens for me most often when I have the font size increased to 125% in the Windows 10 display settings.

Try setting the Font Size scaling to 100% and then log out; it should be *better* when you login and relaunch. This imperfect solution works for me 90% of the time, and is faster than reinstalling.

**note** if the scaling is already set to 100% then set it higher, and then back down to 100%.